# MFC displaying multiple-lines of text in Edit Control box

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to implement a tool that displays file names.
I would like to do this by using SetWindowText() method.
However, When I was trying to use this method in a loop,
the text is displayed in one line and it is continuously refreshed.

here is code snippet

```
for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
{
  SetWindowText(filenames);
}
```

please help.! thanks.

Comment: Is this your real code? You are showing 10 times filenames, whatever that is

Answer (score 10):

`SetWindowText` replaces the current window text with the string you provide.
So, if you want to show multiple lines with it, you first have to create a multi-line string.

A quick example:

```
CStringArray names;

// Fill names

CString str;
for (INT_PTR i = 0; i < names.GetCount() ; ++i)
{
    str += names[i] + _T("\r\n");
}

c_MyEdit.SetWindowText(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another time-tested method of showing multiple names at once is the list box.  MFC provides a nice wrapper with the CListBox Class (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y04ez4c9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).  This has the added benefit of being scrollable and (optionally) sortable if the list is long.